# google fonts not loading on phonegap

Tags: google-font-api

Google fonts are not loading how would I fix this? Here is the code I have the css is from a tutorial so it should be correct. thank you for any help!

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello It seem you are doing everything right but you need to make sure the div you are typing in has source sans pro as the font.